# Adjacent selector with traversal

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, traversal

I have a situation where I am using a fluid grid that I have built myself. These are parents of two content types I am dealing with: `.media-tile` and `.blurb-tile`.

I have removed excess markup that isn't relevant to this question, but my markup essentially looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
    <div class="media-tile">
      <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- END .media-tile -->
  </div><!-- END .three.columns -->
</div><!-- END .row -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="blurb-tile">
      <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- END .blurb-tile -->
  </div><!-- END .twelve.columns -->
</div><!-- END .row -->
```

My issue is that I have to have specific styling on the `.blurb-tile` content block when it follows `.media-tile`content block (as sometimes it doesn't follow it).

I thought that the following traversal method coupled with an adjacent selector would work:

```
.row .three.columns .media-tile + .row .twelve.columns .blurb-tile {
  /* my properties here */
}
```

However it does not...

In this specific situation, is there a selector that I can use along with traversal in order to create a conditional class for when my `.blurb-tile` content block follows my `.media-tile` content block?

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There isn't a concept of traversal in CSS selectors. So you can't, for example, traverse from a descendant to its ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current DOM structure isn't possible with pure css(at least with my css knowledge). I provide a jquery solution for your needs:

```js
$(".media-tile")
  .parents(".row") //get ancestors elements with class row
  .next() //get next element(similar to css adjustment selector)
  .find(".blurb-tile") //find element with class blurb-tile
  .css("color", "red");//apply css for test purposes
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="three columns">
    <div class="media-tile">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="blurb-tile">
      this
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I fix some of your html errors.

**References**

[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: If you use `.find()` in the way you have suggested won't that just find the next `.blurb-tile` and not necessarily see if it specifically follows `.media-tile`?

Comment: @DanMad For example you are missing closing quotes. No if you don't use `next` it will find all `.blurb-tile`.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was looking for. But, it does technically solve my problem, so I will accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @DanMad Glad that I helped you.